# socket issues with angularJS and NodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, angular-socket-io

I need an help: I am trying to send an **emit socket** event to the server side. Could you please help me to find out the error ?
Please consider the enviroment : client files and server files are running on the same server.

**AngularJS:**

```
<!-- Socket.io //bower_components/angular-socket-io/mock/socket-io.js-->                
var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000");      
socket.emit("test","{'xxx': 'yyy'}");
```

**NodeJs:**

```
//"socket.io": "^1.7.4",
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
      socket.on('test', function (data) {
            console.log("receiving data: " , data);   
      });
)}
running with : nodemon push.js 3000
```

Thanks in advance.
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code: `socket` instead of `sockets`.Besides that you're not initializing `io` as explained in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io#how-to-use)

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {    
      socket.on('test', function (data) {
            console.log("receiving data: " , data);   
      });
)}

server.listen(3000)
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work either

io.socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: @Gelso77, I edited the answer. it is `io.on` instead of `io.socket.on`